# Random "CALayerInvalidGeometry Reason: CALayer position contains NaN" exception

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios, calayer

In native xamarin ios project occasionally I am getting exception "Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: CALayerInvalidGeometry Reason: CALayer position contains NaN" at dequeuing UITableView cell. At two different tables.

The main point is that existing of problem randomly depends on build: on specific build app crashes either always or never.
Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Which can happen this issue is that you implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: in your table view delegate and return a bad height (or one of the according header or footer methods).So can you provide the sample?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it can result such exception, but I've tried to remove delegate completely. It looks like some xamarin bug. Now changing to UICollectionView with manually calculated heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing helped. It looks like some xamarin bug. Gone after using collection view instead of table view.